# Numbers whose digits, in order, display prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

There's a post in  [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217960/is-it-a-lobster-number) which asks for code to find numbers whose digits contain their prime factors without rearrangement.  The author suggests the mathematical definition is

> "Determine if the number n is a composite number such that all prime
> factors of n are a subsequence of n"

What I'm wondering is: are there any such numbers where not only are all prime factors found, but, if a prime factor is repeated N times in the factorization, then that prime number can be found in N independent subsequences within the composite number.

Or even more difficult: if we only allow contiguous subsequences, do any such numbers exist?

Comment: Any prime number where $1$ appears as a digit exactly once will work.

Comment: @user44191  sorry, I should have emphasized the  *composite* number part of the conjectures

Comment: Are you interested in $2^59^2=2592$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  that would be yet another variation in the puzzle :-) .  For my current form, I'd need   2^5*9^2 to map to  , e.g.   222223333  or  232323232

Comment: I wrote a program to check for this condition, and I think the logic is correct; I've checked up to 520,000 overnight and haven't found any matching numbers yet.
Don't know how one would go about a proof of existence/nonexistence.  Maybe something with the factors, the numbers, and a matrix?

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, I believe that a composite number can have at most the same number of digits as its prime factors combined, so the multiset of the digits of the number would have to be equal to the multiset of the digits of all the prime factors. i.e. you can't have a bigger or smaller number of digits in the number than you have in the combined prime factors.  Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: @IronEagle  I suppose I could modify the problem so you can re-use digits for different primes,  e.g.   use "23" for 2, 3, and 23 .

Comment: It actually helps if you're trying to find a solution numerically, because you can just compare the list of prime factors with the sorted digits of the number itself: if they are not identical, it's not a solution.  No need to generate substrings, etc.

Comment: If you're interested in the substring, rather than subsequence, version where repeats are allowed, it's https://oeis.org/A050694

Comment: Code crashed at around 249,000,000 with nothing found.  My guess is that if found, it will be analytically, not numerically. I'm probably stopping my efforts here, if someone else wants to try numerically my code is at https://github.com/AD-Wright/StrongLobsters

Comment: Checking up to 2^31 still reveals no solutions.